# SQLiteException: near "If": syntax error

Tags: sqlite, syntax, if-statement

I am converting a 'SQL Server 2008' stored procedure to 'SQLite'. 
But facing problem with the following query:

```
If (Select Count(UserId) From Users Where RememberMe = 'True') > 1
Update Users Set RememberMe = 'False'
Select UserName From Users Where RememberMe = 'True'
```

While executing the above query in the 'SQLite Administrator' or 'SQLite Expert', I am getting the following error message:

> Error occured: near "If": syntax error

I am a beginner in SQLite.
Please guide me.

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Sqlite does not support `if`. You can use `CASE` instead of it.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite doesn't support stored procedures.

But it looks like your code only updates the Users table to set RememberMe = 'False' for users that had it set to 'True'.  If this is the case, then you don't need to do the If part at all.  This should suffice:

`UPDATE Users SET RememberMe = 'False' WHERE RememberMe = 'True'`;